# Transform objects to array using lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, underscore.js, lodash

I would like to transform an object to an array format.
The input object is

```
{
  "index": {
    "0": 40,
    "1": 242
  },
  "TID": {
    "0": "11",
    "1": "22"
  },
  "DepartureCity": {
    "0": "MCI",
    "1": "CVG"
  },
  "ArrivalCity": {
    "0": "SFB",
    "1": "LAS"
  },
  "Price": {
    "0": 90,
    "1": 98
  }
}
```

And the expected output is

```
[
  {
    "index": 40,
    "TID": "11",
    "DepartureCity": "MCI",
    "ArrivalCity": "SFB",
    "Price": 90
  },
  {
    "index": 242,
    "TID": "22",
    "DepartureCity": "CVG",
    "ArrivalCity": "LAS",
    "Price": 98
  }
]
```

I tried using for loops, but it is getting more complicated. If any one can help me, it would be really thankful.

Comment: Dose none of the answers fulfills what you need? or exactly what you are looking for! we may able to still help! (and that will help the community too)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a `lodash` approach

`_.merge([], ..._.map(obj, (v, k) => _.mapValues(v, ev=> ({[k]:ev}))))`

```js
let inputObj = {
  "index": {
    "0": 40,
    "1": 242
  },
  "TID": {
    "0": "11",
    "1": "22"
  },
  "DepartureCity": {
    "0": "MCI",
    "1": "CVG"
  },
  "ArrivalCity": {
    "0": "SFB",
    "1": "LAS"
  },
  "Price": {
    "0": 90,
    "1": 98
  }
};

let res = _.merge([], ..._.map(inputObj, (v, k) => _.mapValues(v, ev=> ({[k] :ev}))));

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `reduce`-ing the `entries` into an array of objects, iterating over each value of the inner objects:

```js
const input={"index":{"0":40,"1":242},"TID":{"0":"11","1":"22"},"DepartureCity":{"0":"MCI","1":"CVG"},"ArrivalCity":{"0":"SFB","1":"LAS"},"Price":{"0":90,"1":98}}

const output = Object.entries(input).reduce((a, [key, obj]) => {
  Object.values(obj).forEach((val, i) => {
    if (!a[i]) a[i] = {};
    a[i][key] = val;
  });
  return a;
}, []);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys` in combination with `reduce`

```js
let object = { "index": { "0": 40, "1": 242 }, "TID": { "0": "11", "1": "22" }, "DepartureCity": { "0": "MCI", "1": "CVG" }, "ArrivalCity": { "0": "SFB", "1": "LAS" }, "Price": { "0": 90, "1": 98 } }

result = Object.keys(object['index']).map(function(key){
  return Object.keys(object).reduce(function(obj, item){
    obj[item] = object[item][key];
    return obj;
  }, {});
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map the inner values to the according index.

```js
var data = { index: { 0: 40, 1: 242 }, TID: { 0: "11", 1: "22" }, DepartureCity: { 0: "MCI", 1: "CVG" }, ArrivalCity: { 0: "SFB", 1: "LAS" }, Price: { 0: 90, 1: 98 } },
    result = Object
        .entries(data)
        .reduce(
            (r, [k, o]) => Object
                .entries(o)
                .map(([i, v]) => Object.assign(r[i] || {}, { [k]: v })),
            []
        );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

With lodash you just need to use [`_.reduce()`](https://lodash.com/docs/#reduce) and [`_.forEach()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#forEach) methods, like this:

```
const result = _.reduce(Object.entries(object), function(a, [key, obj]){
  _.forEach(Object.values(obj), function(val, i){
    if (!a[i]) a[i] = {};
    a[i][key] = val;
  });
  return a;
}, []);
```

**Demo:**

```js
const object = {
  "index": {
    "0": 40,
    "1": 242
  },
  "TID": {
    "0": "11",
    "1": "22"
  },
  "DepartureCity": {
    "0": "MCI",
    "1": "CVG"
  },
  "ArrivalCity": {
    "0": "SFB",
    "1": "LAS"
  },
  "Price": {
    "0": 90,
    "1": 98
  }
};

const result = _.reduce(Object.entries(object), function(a, [key, obj]){
  _.forEach(Object.values(obj), function(val, i){
    if (!a[i]) a[i] = {};
    a[i][key] = val;
  });
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.core.js"></script>
```